# geoserver manager tutorial add new WFS layer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, references, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-manager

`GeoServer Manager` is a library to interact with `GeoServer 2.x`. I want to use it. but I didn't find any appropriate documentation for it. Can anyone help me by some tutorial or example?

here is a few examples : [geo-solutions examples for geoserver manager](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/gs_manager.html)
GeoServer-Manager wiki on GitHub: [here](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki)
For example I want to add a new `WFS` layer into a certain `workspace` of geoserver. suppose I have a shafefile(.shp) and I want to add it into geoserver by geoserver-manager. How can I do that? here is the initial code:

```
String RESTURL  = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver";
String RESTUSER = "admin";
String RESTPW   = "geoserver";

GeoServerRESTReader reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
```

Comment: Did you find the javadoc? You already have the examples and wiki. Can you ask a more specific question about it, rather than "some web link"?

Comment: I want this question to be a source for accessing geoserver-manager tutorials.

Comment: A question isn't meant to be a link-fest...

Comment: I recommend using the links in your question, and then if you get stuck, write up precisely what you are trying to do and where you are stuck as a more focussed question.  Another tip is that help with code is usually more forthcoming when you show where you are stuck in a code snippet of your own.

Comment: @BradHards I changed my question. Hold off please!

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is. You've copied some code, but not tried it yourself. You haven't shown an error message.